# Double integrals explanation

Tags: calculus

Firstly, in my class we have done this example:

We have the region R with : $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $x^2 - 1 \leq y \leq 1-x^2$ with $f(x,y) = 1$

He then calculated the double integral as follows: $\int \int_R 1 \ dx \ dy = \int_{-1}^1G(x) \ dx$

where $G(x) = \int_{x^2-1}^{1-x^2} 1 \ dy$

Now, I have an example here: A region R be described by the inequalities $0 \leq x \leq 2-y$ and $0 \leq y$, sketch the region R and compute the double integral of $f(x,y) = 2x + y^2$ over R.

Here, the inequalities of x and y are different from what we have done as an example in class, so I computed the integral as follows:

$\int \int_R (2x+y^2)\ dy \ dx = \int_0^2 G(y) \ dy$

where $G(y) = \int_0^{2-y} (2x + y^2) \ dx$

Now, is this a correct approach? Also, my main question is how can we just change the order of $\ dx \ dy$ to suit our need?

Comment: @FelixCastor You are putting the cart before the horse. The reason why you have to evaluate the integral over $x$ first is because we chose to describe the region $R$ by bounds on $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ is bounded by $y$ whereas $y$ is not bounded by $x$. If you change the order of integration so that the y-integral is evaluated first, then you don't have to evaluate the x-integral first.

Comment: You are correct.  I removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you did is true.
Second to change the order it will be
$$\int \int_R (2x+y^2)\ dy \ dx = \int_0^2 G(x) \ dx$$
where
$$G(x)=\int_0^{2-x} (2x+y^2)\ dy $$
[image]

In your class example the region is
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but why is it when you change the order, it's still $\int_0^2 G(x) \ dx$ - while as in the example we done in class, it was like that with $\ dx \ dy$ while now it's $\ dy \ dx$ It seems as though you've replaced y with x with your example - I'm not sure why?

Comment: Take the limits of the first integral from the slide and take the limits of the second integral from the least value to the greatest value. In this example both the least value and greatest value of x and y are 0 and 2. Moreover, in the class example, if you want to change order you have to divide the region into two regions, I will add a picture to explain.